# unindent does not match any outer indentation level this a game for space invaderss

Tags: python

what did I do wrong in my code it says this error message unindent does not match any outer indentation level in the code can u rewrite it  to tell me where to change

```
import pygame

# Intialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((800, 600))

# Caption and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")
icon = pygame.image.load("spaceship (1).png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('space-invaders(1).png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480


def player():
    screen.blit(playerImg, (playerX, playerY))


# Game loop
running = True
while running:

    # RGB = Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           running = False



   player()
   pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at following section:

```
while running:

    # RGB = Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

   for event in pygame.event.get():
```

You see that for is indented one character less then tho lines above.

This is your error.

so indenting `for` by one character more should solve the issue:

```
while running:

    # RGB = Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
```

Just a typing / formatting error.

Please check if it works, tell me and I will delete my answer and you can close the question.

If I understood well. typo / formatting questions should be deleted from stack overflow.